# How to get tkinter Spinbox's value?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a timer on python Tkinter. To set the timer, I am using spinboxes. But, I am having trouble getting the value of my spinboxes to be turned into the variables `time_h`, `time_m` and `time_s`.

I have tried `.get()` but it is not working. When I tried printing the variables I got `NameError: name 'spin_h' is not defined`.

```
from tkinter import * 
window = Tk()
window.title("Timer")
window.geometry('350x200')
hour = 0
minute = 0
second = 0
timer = (str(hour) + ':' + str(minute) + ':' + str(second))
lbl = Label(window, text=timer, font=("Arial Bold", 50))
hour_s = 0
min_s = 0
sec_s = 0
def save_time():
    time_h = spin_h.get()
    time_m = spin_m.get()
    time_s = spin_s.get()

def new_window():
    set_time = Tk()
    spin_h = Spinbox(set_time, from_=0, to=10, width=5)
    spin_h.grid(column=1,row=0)
    spin_m = Spinbox(set_time, from_=0, to=60, width=5)
    spin_m.grid(column=3,row=0)
    spin_s = Spinbox(set_time, from_=0, to=60, width=5)
    spin_s.grid(column=5,row=0)
    h_label = Label(set_time, text='h', font=("Arial Bold", 10))
    h_label.grid(column=2, row=0)
    m_label = Label(set_time, text='m', font=("Arial Bold", 10))
    m_label.grid(column=4, row=0)
    s_label = Label(set_time, text='s', font=("Arial Bold", 10))
    s_label.grid(column=6, row=0)
    set_button = Button(set_time, text="Set Time", command=save_time)
    set_button.grid(column=3, row=2)



btn = Button(window, text="Set Time", command=new_window)
btn.grid(column=3, row=2)
lbl.grid(column=3, row=0)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: `spin_h` is a variable local to the `new_window()` function and there cannot be accessed by the `save_time()` function. You could declare it a `global` variable at the beginning of `new_window()` to fix that.

Comment: @martineau , Thanks so much. This has answered my question!

Comment: RAW_tech: You're welcome. Note that while making it a global variable fixes the problem, I feel you should also understand that using globals is generally considered a poor programming practice — but since avoiding them often requires more code, folks often do it anyway (especially in tkinter applications, it seems).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`spin_h` is a variable local to the `new_window()` function and there cannot be accessed by the save_time() function. You could declare it a global variable at the beginning of `new_window()` to fix that. - #Martineau (just made it into an answer instead of a comment).

Thanks Martineau